# Is there a way to count how many file still not yet be compiled

Tags: ios, iphone

I am migrating a old project to a new project.
Once I add all .h/.m files and compile, it will reports error number and stop.
I used cloc to count the number of all objective-c files is 600

Is it possible to get how many files have been compile.

Your comment welcome

Comment: Interesting question but I would like to know that what is your requirement behind counting of compiled classes? If you can share your requirement, I can help you if I know any other way.

Comment: please provide the error msg when it stops...you can read about penetration testing ios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get list of compile file as below -

[image]

If you have huge number of files then you can export below report into text file and make count on this to get compile number of files.

I don't have idea about how to do with run script , above step is manual process .